# How to restrict a user to rbash when logging in via SSH

Tags: ssh, bash

I would like to restrict some users on my server to only being able to execute certain commands. To do this, the most common approach that I could find is to use `rbash`.

While I can find many websites talking about rbash, I am having trouble to find any information how to use it right. The most common approach that I could find was to create a symlink from `/bin/rbash` to `/bin/bash`, set the restricted users’ login shell to `/bin/rbash` and then set a custom `PATH` in `~/.bash_profile` in the user home directory.

However, I was quite shocked to find out that with this setup users can still copy files to the server using `scp` and they can even open an unrestricted shell by using `ssh user@host -t bash`! What seems to be happening is that the SSH server is passing the command to the login shell on the server using `-c`, so `ssh user@host -t bash` causes the server to run `/bin/rbash -c bash`, which works because `.bash_profile` is not executed yet to restrict the path. `scp` similarly causes the server to run `/bin/rbash -c scp`.

Now I have come across the [`ForceCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5#ForceCommand) directive of sshd. This directive basically always causes the configured command to be passed as `-c` to the login shell, ignoring any command that the client has specified. So if `ForceCommand` is set to `rbash`, that will always execute the command `/bin/rbash -c rbash` on the server, regardless whether the client was called with `-t bash` or as `scp` or whatever. Unfortunately, `/bin/rbash -c rbash` causes the `.bash_profile` not to be executed, so we end up with a restricted shell but a normal `PATH`, so we can just call `bash` there to escape it.

What I would like to achieve:

- There should be no way to avoid the restricted shell for users connecting via SSH
- Ideally, it would still be possible to execute commands that are permitted in the restricted shell by using `ssh user@server permitted_command`
- The configuration should not be SSH-only, so users logging in for example on the TTY should also be restricted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with this for a while it seems to me that the root of the problem is that the security of `rbash` depends on `PATH` being set, but in most setups `PATH` is set *after* SSH specifies its custom commands, whereas it needs to be specified *before*.

As a solution, rather than specifying `/bin/rbash` (symlink to `/bin/bash`) as the login shell, I have created a shell script `/usr/local/bin/rbash` and used that as the login shell instead. The shell script has the following content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -l
export PATH=/usr/local/rbin
exec /bin/bash -r "$@"
```

I also experimented with the [`SetEnv`](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5#SetEnv) directive of sshd and tried to set the `PATH` there. However, I found this solution less practical because it sets the configuration only for SSH, and also it caused lots of errors while running `/etc/profile`, because the commands used there could not be found. Also, there seems to be a risk that some other sshd directives would allow the client to override certain environment variables again.